Magento Partial Layered Navigation
So my boss asked me to help with his website. He wanted to be able to filter products via attributes. I made some progress but i come across issues like this:

full web screenshot
where the attribute only shows one product, as opposed to the various products associated with it.


I don't have much experience with Magento, truthfully i just log into it from google and try to figure it out as i go, but i have yet to figure this out after 3 days. thank you.
the category is anchored, all products are in the same category with the same attribute set. and not every product in this category have the attribute set to the same value. I have reindexed, cleared cache. sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

can you send full page screenshot ?

of the website or the magento dash?

both side where all the 23 products are displayed

done, should be in the post now
